# How to deploy angular7 universal server side rendering to IIS

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-seo

In Angular 7 project, deployed the code using ng build --prod to create a production build and copied the content of the dist folder to IIS folder and it works fine.

I tried to implement Angular SEO friendly using @ng-toolkit/universal, It is working fine on my local machine using npm run build:ssr and npm run serve:ssr. Now I need to deploy this application to IIS on webserver. 
I have copied the following folders

[image]

**web.config** (1) contains

[image]

**web.config** (2) contains

[image]

It throws the following error
[image]

Please guide me how to resolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Well, is it it the case? Is your `node.exe` in a directory from `PATH` env var? If not,  do you have a `<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\FullPathTo\node.exe" />` config in your `web.config?`

Comment: @David, Yes, I have added this <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" /> statement in web.config file, then it shows the following exception  - "HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'."

I have added security full access IIS_USERS and IUSER to application root directory. still it throws the same exception. 

Any idea how to resolve this issue.